# Как программно узнать версию exe?

Tags: c#

В свойствах файла есть поле "Версия файла". Как программно получить версию?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/1755504/5752652

Comment: FileVersionInfo.GetVersionInfo(filePath).FileVersion

Comment: ассоциация: https://stackoverflow.com/q/1755504/5752652

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Используйте [FileVersionInfo.FileVersion](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.fileversioninfo.fileversion.aspx):

```
FileVersionInfo myFileVersionInfo = FileVersionInfo.GetVersionInfo(@"C:\asdf.dll ");
```

Пример.

Исходный файл в проводнике:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Данные полученные программным путём:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Вы закрасили имя файла в таблице, но не в заголовке.